# Tangents are drawn from origin to y = cos(x). Find the locus of points of contact of these tangents.

Tags: calculus

Tangents are drawn from origin to y = cos(x). Find the locus of points of contact of these tangents.

If we take an arbitrary point (h,cos(h)) we get the slope at that point as -sin(h). Then the equation of the tangent through that point will be :
y = -xsin(h).
To find the point of contact:
cos(h) = h (-sin(h))

But this does not give us the locus of points of contacts. How do I proceed?

Comment: Isn't is $$-\sin(h)$$?

Comment: Oh.. yes it's  -sinh. Silly me.

Comment: Then you have to solve $$-\frac{1}{h}=\tan(h)$$

Comment: But how does that give us the locus?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're nearly there.

As you say, the slope of the tangent at $(h,\cos h)$ is $-\sin h$, so the equation of that line is $$y-\cos h=-\sin h(x-h)$$  But we also know that this line must go through the origin.  So, we set $x=y=0$ and solve for $h$.

$$0-\cos h=-\sin h(0-h)\\-\cos h=-\sin h(-h)\\h=-\cot h$$

So the locus of points of contact is $\{(x,\cos x)\mid x=-\cot x\}$.